# Form Included in the other form?

Tags: forms, symfony

What should I do when I need to load data in the form from two entities ?
I should include one form in the second form or there is other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two classes extending AbstractType for each entity and use them in a third class (also extending AbstractType)

```
class AType extends AbstractType { ... }

class BType extends AbstractType { ... }

class CType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('a', new AType(), array(...));
        $builder->add('b', new BType(), array(...));
    }
}
```